# Bouncing Animated View in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

I'm trying to implement a view similar to something like: https://bouncingdvdlogo.com/ but for a piece of text.

My first thought was that I could just create an animated loop for both the X and Y axis and just set the `top` and `left` styles on an `Animated.Text`. The catch here is that I don't know what size the text will be exactly until runtime.

I first attempted to use `measure` to get the values then start the animation but `measure` isn't a function available on `Animated.Text`. Is there a simpler approach to solve this animation problem?

Comment: Is `measure` available on `Animated.View`? If so, probably `<Animated.View><Text>Some Text</Text></Animated.View>`? Wrap the text with an animated view tag

Comment: @K.Wu measure isn't available on `Animated.View` either but i found a different approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up trying a different approach that has worked pretty well. I hope anyone else who comes across this finds it useful.

Basically rather than trying to measure the div and calculate its position I animated the `flex` property of some wrapping divs to achieve the same affect.

Here's a demo that shows how this works: https://snack.expo.io/rkNs_CR2G

I've added colors to the animated flex divs to visualize what's going on.